# Cannot create a UIColor using colorFromPatternImage:

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

The following works without issue:

```
toolBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"window_bkd.png"]];
```

However, I have similar statements scattered throughout my code and wanted to clean it up using the following statements, which crash on executing the first statement:

```
UIColor *bkdColor = [[UIColor alloc] colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"window_bkd.png"]];
toolBar.backgroundColor = bkdColor;
[bkdColor release];
```

Console output from the crash:

```
[UIPlaceholderColor colorWithPatternImage:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5203c90
```

Thanks for your help, I'm sure this is a Homer Simpson "doh!" mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You accidently placed an alloc call in your second version, so you are calling `colorWithPatternImage` on an instance, while it is a class method. Doh! :-)
This is how it's done correctly:

```
UIColor *bkdColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"window_bkd.png"]];
```

Comment: Yep, that's a doh!. Thank you!